# Ada Modeless Subprogram Parameters

Tags: ada

If a parameter in Ada is left modeless, what happens?

what is the difference between

```
procedure my_func ( param_1 : in param_type )
```

and

```
procedure my_func ( param_1 : param_type )
```

I am new to ada and have been writing most of my procedures as the latter.  The program compiles and runs as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference - if no parameter mode is given, the compiler assumes "in".

See http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-1.html line beginning 18/3.

-- Martin

Comment: It used to be that all function parameters were `in`, so many of us felt it was pointless to state the `in`. I find I still do!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Martin, the default mode is 'in' if not provided.

I would like to add that if possible, you can sometimes experiment with things about which you are doubtful.
like look at the below simple code, I have not given any mode to the arguement 'no_1'.
And as seen I am assigning value of 'no_2' to it.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure just_testing is

    procedure get_value (no_1 : Integer);

    procedure get_value (no_1 : Integer) is
        no_2 : Integer := 2;
    begin
        no_1 := no_2;
    end get_value;

begin

    Put("auto mode");

end just_testing;
```

And when I compile this code, look what we get as error.

```
>gnatmake just_testing.adb
gcc -c just_testing.adb
just_testing.adb:10:09: assignment to "in" mode parameter not allowed
gnatmake: "just_testing.adb" compilation error
```

So, compiler makes it clear that the default mode is 'in', as we can not assign any value to argument with mode in.